# What is the way best way to use emacs for clojure

Tags: emacs, clojure

I used the instructions [here](http://www.braveclojure.com/basic-emacs/#2__Configuration), it works fine but it seems that I lost the `.emacs` file so I don't know where to add any new configuration.

Is there a standard way to use Clojure on emacs?

Comment: You can create a new blank `.emacs` file and put it in your home directory; or, create a file called `init.el` and put it inside the invisible folder called `~/.emacs.d` which is automatically created in your home directory when launching Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a customized emacs like [prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) or [emacs-live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live)? they both come with built-in support for clojure, and are quite easy to configure.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [clojure-mode](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode).  You can install it by [adding the MELPA repository](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started), and adding the following code snippit to your emacs initialization file.

```
(unless (package-installed-p 'clojure-mode)
     (package-install 'clojure-mode))
```

Comment: As an aside, [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) is very helpful for managing your emacs configuration.